# Given an object with two locations and orientations, how do I find the rotation axis?

Tags: transforms, quaternion

I have an object that I want to animate between two orientations (and locations). I know that rotation axis is close to one end of the object, but not exactly where. How can I figure out where the rotation axis should be so that rotating *only* around that axis will move the object between the two locations and orientations?

I know roughly where the rotation axis is, but looking for the correct location and orientation of that axis using trial and error is very tedious.